# In-Place Editing With Meteor: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: meteor

I have in-place editing set up for a `network` model. There are two input fields, for the `title` and the `description` of the model. When the user clicks on the title, it switches out the `<h2>` tags for an `<input>`, much as in the canonical Todos example.

I am adding events to the relevant template like this:

```
Template.network_edit.events = {}

Template.network_edit.events['click #network-description'] = -> 
    Session.set('editing_network_description',true)
    Meteor.flush()
    focus_field_by_id('network-description-input')

Template.network_edit.events['click #network-title'] = -> 
    Session.set('editing_network_title',true)
    Meteor.flush()
    focus_field_by_id('network-title-input')
```

The `focus_field_by_id` function is,

```
  var focus_field_by_id = function (id) {
  var input = document.getElementById(id);
  if (input) {
    input.focus();
    input.select();
  }
};
```

Everything works as expected, but when I click on the `#network-description`, I see an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

Thrown at line 600 of `liveui.js`. When I click on `#network-title`, I receive no such error.

If I reverse the order of the events, putting the `#network-title` event first, and the `network-description` second, I receive the error when I click on the `#network-title` instead. In general, the first event added throws this error, but not subsequent events.

As I said, everything appears works properly (the inputs appear, gain focus, etc.), but the error is disconcerting and I may be missing something.

Comment: Is this project deployed somewhere that I can look at it? Please post your `focus_field_by_id` function.

Comment: I added the definition of the focus_field_by_id function, though the error is thrown even if those calls are commented out. I do not have this published anywhere at the moment, but will do so.

Comment: hmm, I don't think the bug is in this code.  The error implies something was not defined, and in meteor that usually means the database hasn't finished loading. Or a template helper returned null when you were expecting an object. Or a session variable hasn't been set yet. Those are the places I would look FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem can be narrowed down to the `Meteor.flush()` call. If I comment that out, I do not receive the error. I can make everything run without error if I wrap the last two lines in Meteor.defer, as in `Meteor.defer Meteor.flush(); focus_field_by_id('network-description-input')`

Comment: Very strange.  Although, the fact that `Meteor.defer` seems to fix it further supports the idea that something hadn't finished loading. `Meteor.defer` is just a wrapper around setTimeout. I wish I could offer a real answer - sorry.

Comment: I'm going to try to reproduce this tomorrow.  What version or branch of Meteor are you using, and what does your HTML look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, I was able to reproduce this.

This is a bug that occurs when the DOM is mutated during event handling.  After the call to `Meteor.flush()`, the original target of the event is no longer in the template.  Meteor's event processing code chokes, probably while checking to see if the second handler applies, hence why the first one seems to break.  The error is harmless, and you aren't doing anything wrong.

Event handling is being rewritten for the next release, and I have a regression test in place for this case that the new code already passes.

Thanks for the report and for your patience.