# Exception from Meteor.flush: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been running into a weird bug while working on [Telescope](http://telesc.pe). Currently, clicking submit on a post edit page triggers this error multiple time:

```
Exception from Meteor.flush: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

I've narrowed it down to [post_edit.html](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/05fcbaf1bd9e0e7b45ff3511aa3159c781f6abdf/client/views/posts/post_edit.html#L17-L26):

```
<div class="control-group post-form-category">
  <label class="control-label">Category</label>
  <div class="controls">
    {{#each categories}}
      <label class="radio inline">
        <input id="category_{{_id}}" type="radio" value="{{name}}" name="category" {{#if isChecked }} checked {{/if}}/> {{name}}
      </label>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the `categories` helper:

```
categories: function(){
  return Categories.find();
}
```

If you remove both {{#each}} loops (one in .post-form.category and another one in .post-form-user) the error goes away. Any idea what's going on? Am I doing something wrong with those {{#each}}?

**UPDATE**

It really seems like the problem is coming from the "checked" attribute. But even doing something like

```
<input type="radio" value="{{name}}" name="category" {{isChecked}} />
```

Still triggers the error.

Comment: It may not be related at all, but if you haven't already read it, please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450293/in-place-editing-with-meteor-cannot-read-property-parentnode-of-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is related to a bug in Meteor. Until the bug is fixed, there's a simple solution:

> Make the #each in the SELECT not reactive, by going into post_edit.js and replacing Meteor.users.find() with Meteor.users.find().fetch().

Thanks to @dgreensp

Comment: Sacha, is this bug on github somewhere? I'm having a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925420/meteor-with-datatables-meteor-atflush-typeerror) and haven't been able to fix it with this approach.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if the bug is on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is we don't support `{{#if isChecked }} checked {{/if}}`.  You can't use a block helper (including `#if`) inside an HTML tag; you have to write a helper that returns the appropriate string instead.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon… Even getting rid of the {{#if}} block helper, I still get that error. What's the proper syntax to use checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a reactive Template inside a block helper I made a custom handlebar helper that figures out which category is checked and inserts a string.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('categoriesChecked', function (context, options) {
var ret="";
var i,k, len;
var docs = context.collection.docs;
var lineItem = {};
for (i in docs) {
 lineItem.name = docs[i].name;
 lineItem._id = i;
 lineItem.isChecked = "";
 for (k = 0, len = this.categories.length; k < len; k++) {
  if (this.categories[k] == docs[i].name) {
   lineItem.isChecked = "checked";
  }
 }
ret+= options.fn(lineItem);

}
return ret;
});
```

the .html

```
{{#categoriesChecked categories}}
        <label class="radio inline">
        <input id="category_{{_id}}" type="radio" value="{{name}}" name="category"   {{isChecked}} /> {{name}}
        </label>
{{/categoriesChecked}}
```